# Why AmazonDynamoDB::TYPE_STRING or NUMBER?

Tags: php, amazon-dynamodb

What are these constants defined in Amazon DynamoDB?

Can someone please explain the need of these constants?
Why are these placed in key of associative array?

I see a strange notation during putting items in table like

```
'Name'     => array( AmazonDynamoDB::TYPE_STRING => 'Amazon S3')
```

PHP SDK guide says 4 type of constants.

- TYPE_ARRAY_OF_NUMBERS
- TYPE_ARRAY_OF_STRINGS
- TYPE_NUMBER
- TYPE_STRING

```
$dynamodb->batch($queue)->put_item(array(
'TableName' => 'Forum',
'Item' => array(
    'Name'     => array( AmazonDynamoDB::TYPE_STRING => 'Amazon S3'), // Hash Key
    'Category' => array( AmazonDynamoDB::TYPE_STRING => 'Amazon Web Services'), 
    // Range Key
    'Threads'  => array( AmazonDynamoDB::TYPE_NUMBER => '0')
    )
  ));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These constants reflect the four available [Amazon DynamoDB Data Types](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DataModel.html#DataModelDataTypes):

> **String** - Strings are Unicode with UTF8 binary encoding. There is no limit to the string size when you assign it to an attribute except
>   when the attribute is part of the primary key. [...]
>
> **Number** - Numbers are positive or negative exact-value decimals and integers. A number can have up to 38 digits of precision after the
>   decimal point, and can be between 10^-128 to 10^+126. The
>   representation in Amazon DynamoDB is of variable length. [...]
>
> **String and Number Sets** - Amazon DynamoDB also supports both Number Sets and String Sets.
>   [...] Note that, because it is a
>   set, the values in the set must be unique. String Sets and Number Sets
>   are not ordered; the order of the values returned in a set is not
>   preserved.

You will need to specify or handle these data types in various API calls, e.g. for the *KeySchema* in [CreateTable](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/API_CreateTable.html) or the *Item* in [PutItem](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/API_PutItem.html) as seen in the example you provided.

Answer (score 0):

The newest version of the AWS PHP SDK adds convenience methods to help make formatting your request easier. See the [docs for the attributes() method](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSSDKforPHP/latest/index.html#m=AmazonDynamoDB/attributes). For example:

```
$dynamodb->put_item(array(
    'TableName' => 'my-table',
    'Item' => $dynamodb->attributes(array(
        'id'            => 1,
        'key1'          => 'value1',
        'key2'          => 'value2',
    ))
));
```

Seems much easier to work with this way.